# How can I display a random array position in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I created a method that captures an array and select a random position. I want to display one or more random positions. I use the *ngFor directive to display all position of my array but I have no idea how I can display this random position one;

```
listComics() {
    this.comicsService.getComics().subscribe(
      comicsList => {
        this.comics = comicsList.data.results;
        this.rareComics = comicsList.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.comics.length)]
        console.log(this.comics);
    });
  }
```

and this is how a display the array

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let comic of comics">
      <div class="col">
        <img [src]="comic.thumbnail.path + '/portrait_uncanny.' + comic.thumbnail.extension" id="img"
          (click)="onSelect(comic)">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h5 class="title">{{comic.title}}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You already have the logic to generate a random number and you have also assigned it to the `rareComics` object. Now you only need to do interpolation to display the object details.

Comment: You're right. I was tired and forgot about interpolation. Now I have another question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function to serve your purpose

```
function listRandomComics(comics){
    var radomLength = Math.floor(Math.random()*comics.length)
    var randomArray = []
    for(var i=0; i<=radomLength; i++ ){
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*comics.length)
        randomArray.push(comics[randomIndex])
        comics.splice(randomIndex, 1)
    }
    console.log(randomArray)
}
```

And in ES6

```
listRandomComics(){
    let arr = [...this.comics]
    let randomLength = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
    let randomArray = []
    while(randomLength){
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
        randomArray.push(arr[randomIndex])
        arr.splice(randomIndex, 1)
        randomLength--
    }
    console.log(randomArray)
}
```

Thanks!